# PUT and POST methods with REST in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, rest

We cannot create a list item using PUT method in REST, it gives a bad request error. The REST [reference](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) suggests that the PUT method is generally used to update resources.

Is there a clear distinction for what operations in SharePoint REST we should use PUT and POST. Which scenarios do we use PUT method when working with REST in sharepoint.

Comment: Please refer msdn link for PUT, POST, DELETE and GET http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx . They have written very clearly about these methods.

Comment: @Amit how can I use PUT to update a list / library column value? (more info here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/238527/get-column-values-where-filename-is-x)