# Get column values where filename is x

Tags: document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, file

I'm working with [SharePoint API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest). I'd like to check a `status` column value, which is changed to "new" when a new document is uploaded and changed throughout our ETL process.

I'm accessing the file via:

```
"https://oursite.sharepoint.com/teams/ourorg/ourorgsite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('DataServicesDocs/myProject/')/Files('sharepoint_test.csv')"
```

But this doesn't get me the column of the file in the library in which it exists. JSON properties I get are:

- MajorVersion
- MinorVersion
- ServerRelativeURL
- Name

Etc.

Where is:

- Name
- Modified
- Modified By
- Status (custom field)

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need below:

/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('DataServicesDocs/myProject/')/Files('sharepoint_test.csv')?$expand=ListItemAllFields

It will return files properties along with associated list item properties.

Comment: do you know how I can make a `PUT` request to update said column name? I'd like to use the REST API to change the `status` column's value.